# Getting data out of a "data-" attribute into a JavaScript Var (working with prefixes question)

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I've been learning myself to use the "data-" attribute, and it's going quite well.
But to acces the data inside the attribute I can't quite figure out one thing yet, see below;

(Please Note: the code snippets below are not the actual code but practice examples)

Example that works, and what I understand:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var uip = test1.dataset.userinp
    document.getElementById("uipvalue").innerHTML = uip;
    console.log("current value of userinp: " + uip)
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test11{
    width:100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.test11[data-userinp='abc'] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
}
.test11[data-userinp='def'] {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
        <div data-userinp=abc id="test1" class="test11">
        <p style="padding-top:6px;"> Current "data-" value: <span id="uipvalue"></span></p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Example that I can't get to work, and I don't (yet) understand:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var uip = wpws-test1.dataset.userinp
    document.getElementById("uipvalue").innerHTML = uip;
    console.log("current value of userinp: " + uip)
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test11{
    width:100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.test11[data-userinp='abc'] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
}
.test11[data-userinp='def'] {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
        <div data-userinp=abc id="wpws-test1" class="test11">
        <p style="padding-top:6px;"> Current "data-" value: <span id="uipvalue"></span></p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Alright, so a little more info:
The first example is what works and gets the result I want.
The second example is de situation that I need to get to work.

The difference between the two is the ID of the div, which has gotten a prefix.
And no I can't remove the prefix :)

I'm reading a lot of things about camelCase, and I have tried a fair amount of things with it. But I'm just missing something and I'm stuk...

- Preferred method is JavaScript

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var uip = wpws-test1.dataset.userinp` isn't valid JS (variable names can't contain dashes).

Comment: Yeah I now and discovered that, but I can't figure out what to replace it with to get it to work. As I mentioned I tried some camelCase stuff that I found online. But haven't had any luck yet... and I've run out of google terms to be honest, I don't now where to look at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody can help you with this information. `wpws-test1` is not a variable name. You need to correctly reference your dataset. Where is it coming from? Where is it defined? Is it on the window object?: `var uip = window['wpws-test1'].dataset.userinp`. The information you've provided is insufficient.

Comment: I can't see a way to mark you're answer as "correct", but the code you suggested actually did work with the example I gave. It did exactly what I wanted, but it didn't work in my final code. Turns out I needed to parse the data, but I got to that with youre help really. Thanks!